# r - grepl, search a data frame for a list of patterns and note the row(s) each pattern was found

Tags: r, grepl

I'm hoping this is an easy fix that I'm just not seeing...I have a function that searches a list of patterns across a data frame and then saves the output as a TSV:

```
dfSubset <- df[apply(df, 1, function(i) any(grepl(paste(my.list, collapse="|"), i))),]
write_tsv(dfSubset, "dfSubset.txt", col_names=TRUE)
```

I need to add a function to this that will create another column in the final data frame, dfSubset, and paste the search term from my.list next to the row where each search term was found.

Here is some fake data I've been using from an answer to another post by eipi10:

```
my.list <- c("035", "566", "60883", "6110", "6752", "6751", "680","681","682","683","684","684",
           "685","686", "7048", "70583","7070", "7078", "7079", "7071", "7280", "72886", 
           "7714", "7715", "7854", "9583", "99662", "99762", "9985")

# Fake data
set.seed(10)
df = as.data.frame(replicate(5, sample(c(my.list, 1e5:(1e5+1000)),10)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Here is an example of the desired output, note the pattern_found column:

```
   V1     V2     V3     V4     V5     Pattern_found
3 100409 100087 100767 100145   7048     7048
4 100682 100583 100336 100895 100719     682
7 100252 100024 100829 100813   7078     7078
```

Thank you for your help and suggestions.

Comment: what is `SSTI.list`?

Comment: SSTI.list is a typo, and is now changed to my.list

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand how the output should look like.

Comment: desired output added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(stringr)
rgx = paste(my.list, collapse='|')

dfSubset$Pattern_found = apply(dfSubset, 1, function(i) str_extract(paste(i, collapse=','), rgx))

> dfSubset
#       V1     V2     V3     V4     V5 Pattern_found
# 3 100409 100087 100767 100145   7048          7048
# 4 100682 100583 100336 100895 100719           682
# 7 100252 100024 100829 100813   7078          7078
```

Answer (score 1):

An idea with base R adding on your `dfSubset`,

```
ind <- unlist(sapply(my.list, function(i) grep(i, do.call(paste, dfSubset))))
data.frame(dfSubset[as.integer(ind),], Pattern_found = names(ind))

#      V1     V2     V3     V4     V5 Pattern_found
#4 100682 100583 100336 100895 100719           682
#3 100409 100087 100767 100145   7048          7048
#7 100252 100024 100829 100813   7078          7078
```

or using `stringi` from scratch in a vectorized way,

```
library(stringi)
df$new <- stri_extract_all_regex(do.call(paste, df), paste(my.list, collapse = '|'), simplify = TRUE)[,1]
df[!is.na(df$new),]

#      V1     V2     V3     V4     V5  new
#3 100409 100087 100767 100145   7048 7048
#4 100682 100583 100336 100895 100719  682
#7 100252 100024 100829 100813   7078 7078
```